# How to get HTML portion of the selected row in the Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've a gridview with checkbox in the first column, I need to get the html of the row portion of the selected row. what is a good way to do this?

Below portion logic is required to get the selected row html.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (!(row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
        //logic required here
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `HTML portion`?

Comment: Html value of the row such as <tr>...</tr>

Comment: May I ask why you should need that if the checkbox is not checked? If you elaborate as to how you are planning to use that we could perhaps provide a different solution.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have html value of the whole gridview and display only the rows that are visible. In the logic, I was doing row.Visible = false and getting the value of the html of entire gridview. That worked fine but due to another requirement, I've to manipulate that logic and get the value of the html without causing any binding issue to gridview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this snippet to get the row as HTML in the GridView `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox cb = e.Row.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;

        if (cb.Checked == true)
        {
            TableRow row = e.Row;

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            row.RenderControl(htw);

            string rowContents = sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did get the html contect of the row like I was looking for but I also had to get the header values as well.  Do you have any clue how can I get the header section of the gridview in this case ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `DataControlRowType.Header` to check if the row is the header row, And if so do the same as when the checkbox is checked in the above snippet.

Comment: Yes,, that helped too but I used GridviewName.HeaderRow.RenderControl(htw) at the beginning  before the method you've provided. Thanks for the help