# HTML parsing C#, get html of selected checkbox only

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

The value of html is stored in string. I need to parse the html and get the html values of tr's with only that are checked. 
For example, 
In the html snippet below, I need to get only tr that are checked.

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th>Day</th>
 <th>Code</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="GridVeiw1_c1_checkbox1" type="checkbox" /></td>
 <td>Sunday</td>
 <td>ABCD</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="GridVeiw1_c2_checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
 <td>Monday</td>
 <td>ABCD</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="GridVeiw1_c3_checkbox1" type="checkbox" /></td>
 <td>Tuesdat</td>
 <td>ABCD</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

For the above I need rows only with checked="Checked". Sample output as below

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <th></th>
 <th>Day</th>
 <th>Code</th>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" id="GridVeiw1_c2_checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
 <td>Monday</td>
 <td>ABCD</td>
</tr>



</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you have unclosed `id=""` attributes in the `<input />` elements so you won't be able to easily use regular-expressions to extract values.

Comment: Invalid HTML is a great argument in favor of using a pre-existing library that can handled mangled HTML properly. But...your question shows now research effort. It sounds like you just want us to write the code for you to get what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML to get content using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038104/parsing-html-to-get-content-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Dai I've edited the post, I missed ' " ' at the ending of the id

Comment: Oh so many ways to solve this from a regex to simple string searching and manipulation depending on how it's going to be used. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I like Jquery for this type of thing.  But that's Javascript...

Comment: If this is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42792444/how-to-get-html-portion-of-the-selected-row-in-the-gridview), i've modified the anwer to filter out the rows with the checked checkbox.